# creating new files with different names in Batch

Tags: batch-file, directory, createfile

In the office we have a extense and well defined file structure , and i have to create a hundreds of directories with the same name but differing in the last numbers.

directory0001
directory0002
...
directory0324

this is what i have done:

```
SET B=0001
SET C=0324

:while1

IF NOT %B%==%C%
(
echo "first loop"
SET COUNTER=0
IF NOT %COUNTER%=1
(
echo "Secoond loop"
mkdir "C:\pathfile\directory00"%B%
SET COUNTER==1
)
else() 
SET B=%B%+1
goto :while1
)
else
(
)
```

I'm not sure whether i'm using properly the operators or not, i'm using what i've found in different posts.

-i'm using windows terminal to debugg the code, there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a FOR loop for exactly this, incrementing a count from one value to the end value:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,324) do if %%i LEQ 9 ( md "C:\pathfile\directory000%i" ) else if %%i LEQ 99 ( md "C:\pathfile\directory00%i" ) else ( md "C:\pathfile\directory0%%i" )
```

This will start at 1, increment by 1, until 324 is reached. The `IF` statement is only needed for formatting leading zeroes.
**Edit:**
this is the complete code with proper indentation so that you (as a novice) can understand the flow more easily:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

REM enable cmd extensions so that mkdir/md will create all intermediate folders

SET first=1
SET last=324

REM numeric extension will be appended with 4 places to this foldername
SET folder=C:\users\goofy\manydirs\directory

FOR /L %%i in (%first%,1,%last%) DO (
    IF %%i LEQ 9 (
        mkdir %folder%000%%i
    ) ELSE IF %%i LEQ 99 (
        mkdir %folder%00%%i
    ) ELSE IF %%i LEQ 999 (
        mkdir %folder%0%%i
    ) ELSE (
        mkdir %folder%%%i
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you user1016274 very clear the code, now it does what i want.


Why the variable "i" is using a different sintax?i mean which is the difference between:


%first%
%%i

Comment: `%i` is used within a `FOR` loop as the variable to which one value from the list is assigned. In a batchfile, you must double the '%', so `%%i`.

Comment: Then always that i declare a variable in a loop , should i do it like this %%i, and outside %i%?is that right?

Comment: No, not quite. I think (but don't count on that too much) that loop variables of the form "%%x" do not exist OUTSIDE the loop. If you want to retain their value at the moment when the loop is exiting you have to assing it to a shell variable.